# boost accumulator tail_quantile, how to get the quantile

Tags: c++, boost

Following my previous question. I modified by code as below accordingly based on the tail_quantile example given in boost 1.55 doc in 
[boost tail_quantile](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_statistical_accumulators_library.tail_quantile)

```
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/tail_quantile.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/framework/accumulator_set.hpp>
#include <boost/random/lagged_fibonacci.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions/normal.hpp>

using namespace boost::accumulators;


void testTailQuantile()
{
    // tolerance in %
    double epsilon = 1;

    std::size_t n = 100000; // number of MC steps
    std::size_t c =  10000; // cache size
    typedef accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::tail_quantile<boost::accumulators::left> > > accumulator_t_left;
    accumulator_t_left acc0( left_tail_cache_size = c );
    boost::lagged_fibonacci607 rng;
    boost::normal_distribution<> mean_sigma(0,1);
    boost::variate_generator<boost::lagged_fibonacci607&, boost::normal_distribution<> > normal(rng, mean_sigma);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        double sample1 = rng();
        double sample2 = normal();
        acc0(sample1);
    }

    std::cout <<    quantile(acc0, quantile_probability = 0.95 ) << std::endl;
}
```

For the last line of code, the "quantile(acc0....." reported an error as below:

```
In file included from ../src/LearnBoost.cpp:16:0:
../src/testBoostAccumulator.h: In function ‘void testTailQuantile()’:
../src/testBoostAccumulator.h:39:58: error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::accumulators::extractor<boost::accumulators::tag::quantile>) (accumulator_t_left&, const type)’
  std::cout << quantile(acc0, quantile_probability = 0.95 ) << std::endl;
```

Have I forgotten some header files or namespaces again?

Comment: Adding either `#include <boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp>` or `#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>` makes your program compile, although I don't know enough about the problem domain/library to know if the obtained result is correct.

Comment: Thank you, it works all right. I changed the "_left" to "_right" and produced good result...